# How is additional rounding error introduced when using f64::mul_add?

Tags: rust, double, precision, floating-accuracy

According to the docs, [`f64::mul_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.mul_add) can be used to reduce the number of opportunities for rounding errors:

> ```
> pub fn mul_add(self, a: f64, b: f64) -> f64
> ```
>
> Fused multiply-add. Computes `(self * a) + b` with only one rounding
>   error.  This produces a more accurate result with better performance
>   than a separate multiplication operation followed by an add.

I am working on a linear transforms library where `a * b + ...` is very common. When I introduced `mul_add` for the dot products of my `AffineVector` struct I **lost** precision.

This is the dot product method:

```
impl AffineVector {
    pub fn dot(self, v: AffineVector) -> f64 {
        self.x * v.x + self.y * v.y + self.z * v.z + self.w * v.w
        //  self.x.mul_add(v.x, self.y.mul_add(v.y, self.z.mul_add(v.z, self.w * v.w)))
    }
}
```

[complete source here](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Rust.Positron.Transforms/tree/master/src)

With the `mul_add` implementation **and no other changes**, the following test fails because of a floating point precision issue on the last assert:

```
#[test]
fn inverse_rotation() {
    // create a rotation matrix for 1 radian about the Z axis
    let rotate = AffineMatrix::new(Primitives::RotationZ(1.));

    // create a matrix that undoes the rotation of 'rotate'
    let revert = rotate.inverse();

    // apply the transformation to the vector <1,0,0>
    let rotated = rotate.apply_vec3(KVector3::i_hat());        

    // assert that the result is <cos(1),sin(1),0>
    let expected = KVector3::new(C, S, 0.0);        
    assert_eq!(rotated, expected);

    // use the 'revert' matrix to undo the rotation
    let returned = revert.apply_vec3(rotated);     

    // assert that the result is back to <1,0,0>   
    assert_eq!(returned, KVector3::i_hat());
}
```

```
panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`   
left: `KVector3 { x: 1.0, y: 0.000000000000000023419586346110148, z: 0.0 }`,  
right: `KVector3 { x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0 }`',
```

How and why did using `mul_add` decrease the precision? How can I use it effectively?

Comment: Why do you believe that you "lost" precision? Seems more likely that previously you had *two* rounding errors that just happened to cancel each other out. Now there's only one error and you can see it.

Comment: that rounding errors across the number of operations involved in this perfectly canceled out seemed extremely unlikely

Comment: Be that as it may, there are *very* few cases where floating-point calculations are exact, and this test does not appear to be one of them. If you wouldn't expect `0.1 + 0.2` to equal `0.3`, you shouldn't expect this test to pass except by random happenstance. (And if you do expect `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`, you should read [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) first.)

Comment: Assuming left-to-right evaluation of addition, the recoding changed the order of the sum, which is high risk to change the rounding.

Comment: I'm going to suggest closing this as a dupe of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) While you're doing more sophisticated transformations, the answers still apply. If you're actually doing something where floating point math should be exact (only binary fractions and no rounding), then that should be in the question.